# How do I stop my friends' garbage residents moving to my island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

After my friends manage to finally get "in boxes" a resident they don't want: if I have an available plot, that "garbage resident" will always take **my** available plot:

- No asking or interaction with the garbage resident required.
- No visiting of that friend for weeks (and vice-versa).

It seems that Nook just "forces" the rejected resident apon their friends.

### How do I block the rejects moving in without my asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an open plot, I believe the game tries to fill it, preferring move-outs from friends.

The only way I know of to stop this from your end is to invite a villager yourself to fill the plot, either from visting islands, amiibo cards, or another leaving villager from another player.

Your friend can also stop this by finding another person that wants their villager.  Some services such as [Nookazon](https://nookazon.com/products/villagers) exist to faciliate this.